# iOS syncing time between devices

Tags: ios, time, synchronization

**Goal:**

Given N devices, I would like to make them start an action which will take 10 seconds precisely and collect these datas in the end. Problem is, all of N devices should start this procedure in the same millisecond.

**Advantage:**

Since the data is going to be collected, I can run further detection about millisecond differences between devices. But this approach also requires another mechanism to detect such behaviour on the server-side.

**Problem:**

What should be my mechanism to sync the "start" time between N devices? 
Can we detect the difference between the device and the server clock (since it will give the same result as syncing time)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Assuming that the messages are received within less than one second on all the devices:

The server sends a message to N devices. This message contains the timestamp of the server along with the time (in future) that the process should begin (e.g. 2000 msec).

Each device will check the timestamp of the server with its own timestamp and calculates the difference. Then starts a timer so that at the precise moment in the future it will start the process.

This way (in theory) the devices start a process at the exact same time.
I said in theory, since this will work if there are no other apps running on the iOS device that already consume process and memory to interfere with your app.

Comment: and how am i supposed the calculate the connection time between the server and device (while getting the timestamp)

Comment: Once a device receives the message from the server, the app should check the current time of the device. Since the message already contains the server time stamp, the app can subtract these two values to have the delta time.

Comment: I pressed the return key and the above message was sent.

To get the current time of the iOS device, you can use

[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

Comment: You'll always have some uncertainty you can't eliminate. If your devices are receiving commands, there's no way (short of low-level network packet inspection) to know how long ago that command was sent from the server and how long it spent traveling to your device over the network. Thus, if your server sends "It's now 10am" there's no way for each device in isolation to know how long it took that message to arrive, and no way for each device to know how much it needs to correct for that network delay.

Comment: Now if your devices are all running on some network where you can either analyze or control network travel time (latency), that's maybe different. But on the global internet, you have zero control or predictability with latency.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. When the device is connected to the server (e.g. not push), speed can vary based on the data connection speed. The original question in the post is asking about the time difference between the server and a device. At any moment in time when the message is received, the device stores the time, reads the message content to extract server timestamp and the delta indicates the difference between server and device time plus connection delay.

Comment: Latency can vary between data packets as well, right? One packet took 10ms, another took 90ms.